# Solr full text search

Tags: solr

Is there a way to index documents with solr that are already on the solr server.

It seems that most of the tutorials I see include uploading the file through a stream before it get indexed. Is there a way to signal to SOLR to index files currently on the file system given a current schema and using tika?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you searched, but there are loads of blog articles about this topic, [like this one](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/05/25/import-folder-of-documents-with-apache-solr-4-0-and-tika/).

If you want to get going with Solr, you should read through the first chapters [of the reference guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Apache+Solr+Reference+Guide), at least till the chapter about searching. This will get you familiar with the concepts of Solr and provide the right vocabulary to google better.